# format a log file using groovy script

Tags: shell-script, jenkins

I need quick help with the below Groovy script; I was fetching the hostname and IPs of the server via Jenkins.

When did a `cat` of that file, I am getting the contents below

```bash
$ cat serverbox_info
abcdefgh
10.10.10.1
bcdefghi
10.10.10.2
yubhgrwp
10.10.10.3
```

The above `serverbox_info` file is dynamic, and it might have more hostname and IPs.

Now I need to have variables where hostname and IP are stored on two variables. For example `abcdefh` will be stored in a variable called `hostname` and IP will be stored in 10.10.10.1

The next time, the value of the next hostname and IP will be stored again in the same variable.

I tried all options, and I am not able to come up with a good code using Groovy. I tried to use a for loop and tried to propagate through the file but can't store them or jump between hostname and IPs in the file.

Thanks

Rajesh

Comment: You mention an existing Groovy script, but the question does not seem to contain any code at all.